# Сортировка и по убыванию, и по возрастанию в зависимости от значения true или false VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Нужно в зависимости от того, какой флаг у чекбокса true или false, сортировать массив по возрастанию числа и наоборот

Помогите пожалуйста с функцией...Сейчас так:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '.movieApp',
    data: {
        randomMovie: null,
        randomMovieDescription: null,
        movies: [
            {
                film: "AMOVIE",
                year: 2012
            },
            {
                film: "CMOVIE",
                year: 2018
            },
            {
                film: "BMOVIE",
                year: 2009,
            }],
        search: '',
        sortByYear: false
        },
        
        methods: {
        sortDate: function () {
            this.sortByYear = !this.sortByYear
            this.movies.sort(function(a, b) { 
                if (this.sortByYear = true) {
                    return b.year - a.year 
                } if (this.sortByYear = false) {
                    return a.year - b.year
                }
            })
        }
        },
```

```html
 <input 
                        class="list__movieList__seenAndSort 
                        list__movieList__seenAndSort__sort" 
                        type='checkbox'
                        id='sortByYear' 
                        v-on:click="sortDate()"
                        v-model="sortByYear"
                    >
                    <label for='sortByYear'> Отсортировать по году</label>
```

но работает функция в одну сторону...При клике на чекбокс (когда чекбокс принимает значение true), массив сортируется по убыванию...Когда чекбокс принимает противоположное значение, массив не сортирутеся по возрастанию, как ожидалось...

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Оператор сравнения `==` или `===`, но не `=` как в строке `if (this.sortByYear = true)`

Comment: пробовала. в таком случае сортировка не работает ни в одну сторону

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменение переменной `this.sortByYear = !this.sortByYear;` мешало нормальной работе. Вы же `v-model` для этой цели использовали :)

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#movieApp',
    data: {
        randomMovie: null,
        randomMovieDescription: null,
        movies: [
            {
                film: "AMOVIE",
                year: 2012
            },
            {
                film: "CMOVIE",
                year: 2018
            },
            {
                film: "BMOVIE",
                year: 2009,
            }],
        search: '',
        sortByYear: false
    },
        
    methods: {
        sortDate() {
            
            this.movies.sort((a, b) => { 
                if (this.sortByYear) {
                    return b.year - a.year 
                } else {
                    return a.year - b.year
                }
            });
            
            
        }
    },
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="movieApp">
 <input
type='checkbox'
@change="sortDate"
v-model="sortByYear">
<label for='sortByYear'> Отсортировать по году</label>
<p v-for="(item, index) of movies" :key="index">{{item.year}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: в таком случае сортировка идет также в одну сторону...А я наоборот и пытаюсь реализовать такое, чтобы при клике на чекбокс, у меня отрисовка массива была по убыванию, когда sortByYear = true, и по возрастанию, когда значение противоположно)

Comment: Нажмите кнопку выполнить код на моём ответе. Код так и работает.

Comment: Просто скопируйте тело моего метода и вставьте вместо своего. Там у вас с `===` есть ещё косяки.

Comment: в том то и дело, что код скопировала) просто у моего приложения логика немного другая, здесь в качестве примера я привела первое, что пришло в голову. Запуталась в названиях, как итог получилось недопонимание.  спасибо!